# text editor for coloured syntax on parentheses/brackets?

Tags: editor

Hi guys I'm looking for a text editor that can have the coloured bracket feature. I'm running sublime text and none of the plugins I use have that feature or they don't work. I use Ubuntu and would like a text editor friendly to my os. https://www.google.com/search?q=rainbow+braces+text+editor&espv=2&biw=1301&bih=681&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI6-XywYzQxwIViHumCh31PQvk#imgrc=Q44WVZreWruUvM%3A is an example

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters

Comment: https://atom.io/ is quite nice and you can customise/choose from a great number of themes - I'm sure I've seen syntax themes with "rainbow brackets". :)

Comment: can you show me a link as i have not seen one